# large dataset for parsing in webpage

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a large dataset of around 600,000 values that need to be compared, swapped, etc. on the fly for a web app. The entire data must be loaded since some calculations will require skipping values, comparing out of order, and so on.

However, each value is only 1 byte

I considered loading it as a giant JSON array, but this page makes me think that might not work dependably: http://www.ziggytech.net/technology/web-development/how-big-is-too-big-for-json/

At the same time, forcing the server to load it all for every request to be a waste of server resources since the clients can do the number crunching just as easily.

So I guess my question is this:

1) Is this possible to do reliably in jQuery/Javascript, and if so how?

2) If jQuery/Javascript is not the better option, what would be the best way to do this in PHP (read in files vs. giant arrays via include?)

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't 600k bytes amount to just about 0.57 megabytes, and that's not really "giant" anything, and should'nt be an issue ?

Comment: Sorry, assume multiple of these files need to be loaded, i.e. assume we're dealing with around 5MB of raw data in nested arrays etc.

Comment: Can you provide us with more info as to where this data is coming from, data files, database...?

Comment: a flat file- either json encoded, regular array, or series of bytes

Comment: Put the json in a `.json` file and check it using this command: `gzip -c filename.min.js | wc -c`. This will tell you the gzipped size - the size that the user will have to download.

Comment: true, but that doesn't tell me how it will affect user's memory during runtime

Answer (score 1):

I know Apache Cordova can make sql queries.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

I know it's PhoneGap but it works on desktop browsers (At least all the ones I've used for phone app development)

So my suggestion:

Mirror your database in each users' local Cordova database, then run all the sql queries you want!

Some tips:
-Transfer data from your server to the webapp via JSON
-Break the data requests down into a few parts. That way you can easily provide a progress bar instead of waiting for the entire database to download
-Create a table with one entry that keeps the current version of your database, check this table before you send all that data. And change it each time you want to 'force' an update. This keeps the users database up-to-date and lowers bandwidth

If you need a push in the right direction I have done this before.